# Dijkstra Algorithm Time Complexity

Tags: algorithm

I am new to Dijkstra Algorithm.

My question is that: for an undirected graph G with n nodes and m edges, the time complexity for Dijkstra Algorithm to find shortestst path is o((n+m)logn). However, if the G is connected, why this time complexity can be also expressed as o(mlogn)?

Cheers

Comment: You've used little-o, but do you mean big theta?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is not connected, say in the case where there is only one edge (m=1), then it can be it is o(nlgn). That is why in the general case it is o((m+n)lgn).

If it is connected, there should be a tree that connects the whole graph (length n-1), so m is at least n-1: (`m>=n-1`). So for purposes of small O notation (Small O:f is dominated by g asymptotically), I can replace n by m: o((m+1+m)lgn) "=" o(mlgn)